# My toString() method isn't overriding the Calendar toString() method

Tags: java, overriding, tostring, overloading

Here is my code, pretty simple really. Its not homework, I'm teaching myself java through an education book:

---

```
import java.util.*;

/** @author Chris */

public class Exercise9_9 extends GregorianCalendar
{   
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String[] stringList = {"s", "c", "b", "f", "e", "q", "g", "w", "i", "o"};
        Integer[] integerList = {5, 7, 8, 9, 6, 5, 4, 1, 2, 3};
        Calendar[] calendarList = new Calendar[10];

        for (int a = 0; a < calendarList.length; a++)
        {
            calendarList[a] = new GregorianCalendar();
            calendarList[a].set(Calendar.YEAR, ((int)Math.random()* 1000));
        }

        System.out.println("Largest String: " + max(stringList));
        System.out.println("Largest int: " + max(integerList));
        **System.out.println("Largeset date: " + (max(calendarList)).toString());**
    }

    public static Object max(Object[] a)
    {
        Arrays.sort(a);
        return a[a.length-1];
    }

    **@Override
    public String toString()**
    {
        return "Test";
    }  
}
```

---

The question is to produce three arrays: int, String and Calendar type. Then pick out the biggest out of each category (and display the answers).

This class extends the `GregorianCalendar` class which means I have access to the Calendars `toString()` which I'm trying to override. However it doesn't work. Its like the `toString()` method isn't overriding because I'm getting the default `toString()` output. However, I'm using Netbeans and it acknowledges the override and even takes me to to `Calendar.toString()` when I click the override link. So I'm stuck, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's because you are not using your class, but `GregorianCalendar`:
`calendarList[a] = new GregorianCalendar();`

change this to
`calendarList[a] = new Exercise9_9 ();`

Comment: Wow, my first question given such a rapid response. Thank you so much.